# How to concatenate binary numbers without using their decimal values? For example 3 and 4 -> 34

Tags: binary, binary-operations

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643002/binary-concatenation) describes exactly what I need to do!

I am also doing this using electronic circuitry. The problem is, that the answer (which has been marked as a 'solution') only works for those two specific numbers.

I simply want to concatenate the base 10 representation of two base 2 numbers together. For example: $(0001)_2+(0010)_2=(1100)_2$ if instead of the plus sign, there were a sign for the operation I want to perform, of course. I need some sort of formula that can do this for any 2 numbers.

Hopefully somebody can help me with this, since the internet has, yet again, let me down!
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Yes yes! My bad! I edited my question. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: What are the operations you can use? Are you able to perform those operations repeatedly (loops)?

Comment: When you say "any two numbers", do you mean **any** two numbers, such as $1234$ and $17980824985098142098$? Or were you looking at something more limited, such as any two decimal numbers of one digit each? Do the two input numbers come with a fixed number of binary digits? In your example it looks like you are dealing with two four-bit binary numbers.

Comment: Your example is incorrect as the result of $1+2$ should be $12_{10}=1100_2$

Comment: @RossMillikan I thought the question already said the result would be $1100_2$, except that it is written $(1100)_2$.

Comment: I edited the question. I mistyped 1010 instead of 1100.
Also, yes. Like I mentioned in my question, I need to be able to do this for ANY 2 (positive) numbers. Be it 95, 23,52,18, 42.
For now, I only need the math for this. I can handle the bit size and everything else later.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is the base $b$ concatenation of integers $x\geq 0$ and $y>0$ is given by $$x\cdot b^{\lfloor\log_by\rfloor +1} + y$$

From here, we can see it ultimately comes down to computing $\lfloor\log_by\rfloor$.  I've never personally looked up how accurately we can compute said logarithms, so I would just preload integral powers of $b$ in whatever base $x,y$ appear in and then compare powers $b^i$ with $y$.

Find $b^n$ such that $b^n \leq y < b^{n+1}$.  Then the concatenation is $$xb^{n+1}+y$$ and the calculation is done in whatever base is natural.

Comment: You can save space by only storing $b^{2^i}$ if you want.  Then perform one pass starting from the largest powers to construct $b^n$.  Whether you use integer division only on the powers you need or multiplication on each one will be up to you.

Comment: Given that this is (apparently) an exercise in circuit building, I think we can assume that there is a (relatively small) maximum value of $\log_b y$. It may even be that we only have single-digit decimal numbers as input.

Comment: @DavidK I don't know those restrictions, but yeah, it might only need a small number of fixed comparisons and a multiplicative counter, or in extreme cases, maybe just a simple if-then structure